# Is there a way to count certain values in an access report's calculated field?

Tags: ms-access, count, reporting, calculated-field

I created a report in access that has a field called [Velocity_Letter].

```
=IIf([Percent_OB]<0.4,"A",IIf([Percent_OB]<0.8,"B",IIf([Percent_OB] <0.9,"C","D")))
```

This field can be either (A,B,C,D) based on another field named [Percent_OB]. The calculated field works great, it provides the correct letter. However, my problem is when trying to count all the records with A's, B's, C's, and D's. I just want to have a total of each letter, but have had no success.

I have tried using the following expressions, but none of them work.

```
=Sum(IIf([Percent_OB]<0.4,1,0))

=Sum(IIf([Velocity_Letter]="A",1,0))

=Count(IIf([Percent_OB]<0.4,0))

=Count(IIf([Velocity_Letter]="A",0))
```

My expected output would be: Total_A =32, Total_B=22, etc. 
My actual results are either "#Error" or a count of every single record.

Comment: Because of the = sign, I presume the Velocity_Letter calc is in a textbox, not a field in query. Aggregate functions must reference a field, not a textbox. "Field" and "textbox" are not synonymous. Do the Velocity_Letter calculation in query, not textbox. Or repeat the entire Letter calc in the aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to view this data in a form or report you can use the DCount function in a TextBox control:

Replace PKColumn with the name of your table's primary key column, and replace TableName with the name of your table

```
=DCount("PKColumn","TableName","Velocity_Letter = 'A'")
```